# Creating an SQL Server Script to check for nulls on any table given in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a stored procedure that will check a table if there are any null values in the table at all. I want this to be able to be called on any table that I ask it to. I'm having a hard time wit the code if anyone could help me please.

```
Create Procedure NullCheck

@table VarChar(128)
as
Begin 
Declare @query Varchar(Max)
set @query = N'WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS ns) 
SELECT * 
FROM' +  QUOTENAME(@table) +  'AS T1 
WHERE (
    SELECT T1.* 
    FOR XML PATH' + '('row')' +', ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE
  ).exist' + '(' + '//*/@ns:nil'+ ')' + '= 1'
  EXEC @query 
  END
```

Comment: Which column your are specifically checking for null? Conditions is valid for all columns? TableA can have 10 columns and TableB can have 50. If any column of any rows of either table is a valid condition?

Comment: Can you post a sample input for the @table var?

Comment: If any row in the table the I specified has a null I want to see the entire row

Comment: The Select statement works perfectly, I just want to be able to call it for any table I specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128) = '[dbo].[SurveyInstances]'; -- or SYSNAME

DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX); 


SET @DynamicSQLStatement = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' +
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ' OR [' +  [name] + '] IS NULL'
        FROM [sys].[columns]
        WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,3
    ,''
);

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement;
```

---

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [sys].[objects] WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[usp_GetRowsWithAtLeastOneNULLvalue') AND [type] IN (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetRowsWithAtLeastOneNULLvalue];
END;
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetRowsWithAtLeastOneNULLvalue] 
(   
    @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
)
AS
BEGIN;

    DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX); 

    SET @DynamicSQLStatement = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' +
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ' OR [' +  [name] + '] IS NULL'
            FROM [sys].[columns]
            WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,3
        ,''
    );

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. This only checks columns that are **nullable**:

```
--/*
create procedure dbo.test_nullCheck (@SchemaName nvarchar(128), @TableName nvarchar(128)) as 
begin
--declare @SchemaName nvarchar(128); 
--declare @TableName  nvarchar(128);
  set @SchemaName =   isnull(@SchemaName,'dbo')
  --set @TableName =  '';
  declare @sql      nvarchar(max);
  declare @select   nvarchar(max);
  declare @from     nvarchar(max);
  declare @where    nvarchar(max);
  select @select = 'select * ';
  select @from   = ' from '+quotename(s.name)+'.'+quotename(o.name)+' '
    from  sys.objects as o 
      inner join sys.schemas as s on o.schema_id=s.schema_id
        and o.is_ms_shipped = 0
        and o.type = 'U'
        and o.name = @TableName
        and s.name = @SchemaName
  select @where = 'where '+
      stuff((
      select ' or '+quotename(c.name)+' is null'
        from sys.columns as c 
          inner join sys.objects as o on c.object_id = o.object_id
             and o.is_ms_shipped = 0
             and c.is_nullable = 1
             and o.type = 'U'
             and o.name = @TableName
          inner join sys.schemas as s on o.schema_id=s.schema_id
            and s.name = @SchemaName
        order by c.column_id
        for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        , 1,4,'')+ ';'
  set @sql = @select + @from + @where 
    print @sql
  if @sql is not null 
    begin
      exec sp_executesql @sql
    end;
end;
--*/
exec dbo.test_NullCheck @schemaname = null, @tablename = 'Calendar' 
  -- does nothing in my database because the schema is ref
exec dbo.test_NullCheck @schemaname = 'ref', @tablename = 'Calendar'
  -- returns rows with nulls
exec dbo.test_NullCheck @schemaname = 'ref', @tablename = 'Calendar; Drop Table Calendar; select * from Calendar'
  -- does nothing because there isn't a table name like that
```